# how to decrease partition size + lvm

Tags: linux, filesystems, rhel, lvm, xfs

on /var we have 101G on the Linux red hat server

```
grep var /etc/fstab
/dev/mapper/vg10-00_var /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
```

we want to decrease it to 30G

```
 df -h /var
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg10-oo_var  101G  3.6G   98G   4% /var
```

so we do:

```
 lvreduce -L -70G /dev/mapper/vg10-00_var
 WARNING: Reducing active and open logical volume to 30.87 GiB
 THIS MAY DESTROY YOUR DATA (filesystem etc.)
 Do you really want to reduce lv_var? [y/n]: y
 Size of logical volume vg10/oo_var changed from 100.87 GiB (25822 extents) 
 to 30.87 GiB (7902 extents).
 Logical volume lv_var successfully resized.
```

but xfs_grow complain about - data size 8091648 too small

```
xfs_growfs /dev/mapper/vg10-00_var
meta-data=/dev/mapper/vg10-00_var isize=256    agcount=26, agsize=1039872 blks
     =                       sectsz=512   attr=2, projid32bit=1
     =                       crc=0        finobt=0
data     =                       bsize=4096   blocks=26441728, imaxpct=25
      =                       sunit=0      swidth=0 blks
naming   =version 2              bsize=4096   ascii-ci=0 ftype=0
log      =internal               bsize=4096   blocks=2560, version=2
      =                       sectsz=512   sunit=0 blks, lazy-count=1
realtime =none                   extsz=4096   blocks=0, rtextents=0
data size 8091648 too small, old size is 26441728
```

why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two things wrong here:

- You need to shrink a filesystem **before** reducing the size of its Logical Volume. Failing to do so will destroy most content of the filesystem (in your case `/var`), as `lvreduce` dutifully warned you.
- A XFS filesystem cannot be shrunk.

Now you should erase the `/var` partition and recreate it from backup, as its content has been borked anyway.

Comment: some tought: there is a **xfs_fsr** to help reorg FS, however reducing/umounting `/var` might be tricky, if even possible. I would have prepared operation on a file based toy xfs filesystem (just in case). On a side note every attempt I make to reduce ext4 filesystem result in a loss of test data.